# How to optimize this kind of loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops, layout, layout-manager

I'm trying to make this GUi.

[image]
I write my own layout because existing layout manager don't meet my requirements
It works but I attempt to optimize the creation of all buttons by using loops.

**Test.class**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel parent = new JPanel();
        f.add(parent);
        parent.setLayout(new BoxLayout(parent, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JPanel[] children = new JPanel[6];
        for (int i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
            children[i] = new JPanel();
            children[i].setLayout(new XYLayout());
            children[i].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
            parent.add(children[i]);
        }

        int x = 0, y = 375, w = 0, h = 50;

        children[1].add(new JButton("8"), new XYConstraints(0, 25, 0, 50));
        children[1].add(new JButton("7"), new XYConstraints(0, 75, 0, 50));
        children[1].add(new JButton("6"), new XYConstraints(0, 125, 0, 50));
        children[1].add(new JButton("5"), new XYConstraints(0, 175, 0, 50));
        children[1].add(new JButton("4"), new XYConstraints(0, 225, 0, 50));
        children[1].add(new JButton("3"), new XYConstraints(0, 275, 0, 50));
        children[1].add(new JButton("2"), new XYConstraints(0, 325, 0, 50));
        children[1].add(new JButton("1"), new XYConstraints(0, 375, 0, 50));

        children[2].add(new JButton("7"), new XYConstraints(240, 25, 0, 100));
        children[2].add(new JButton("6"), new XYConstraints(200, 75, 0, 100));
        children[2].add(new JButton("5"), new XYConstraints(160, 125, 0, 100));
        children[2].add(new JButton("4"), new XYConstraints(120, 175, 0, 100));
        children[2].add(new JButton("3"), new XYConstraints(80, 225, 0, 100));
        children[2].add(new JButton("2"), new XYConstraints(40, 275, 0, 100));
        children[2].add(new JButton("1"), new XYConstraints(0, 325, 0, 100));

        children[3].add(new JButton("6"), new XYConstraints(200, 25, 0, 150));
        children[3].add(new JButton("5"), new XYConstraints(160, 75, 0, 150));
        children[3].add(new JButton("4"), new XYConstraints(120, 125, 0, 150));
        children[3].add(new JButton("3"), new XYConstraints(80, 175, 0, 150));
        children[3].add(new JButton("2"), new XYConstraints(40, 225, 0, 150));
        children[3].add(new JButton("1"), new XYConstraints(0, 275, 0, 150));

        //children[4],//children[5]...



        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
```

The custom layout in one file : XYLayout

```
 public class XYLayout implements LayoutManager2, Serializable {

    private int width;
    private int height;
    Hashtable<Component, Object> info;
    static final XYConstraints defaultConstraints = new XYConstraints();

    public XYLayout() {
        info = new Hashtable<Component, Object>();
    }

    public XYLayout(int width, int height) {
        info = new Hashtable<Component, Object>();
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("XYLayout [width=").append(width).append(", height=").append(height).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public void addLayoutComponent(String s, Component component1) {
    }

    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component component) {
        info.remove(component);
    }

    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
        return getLayoutSize(target, true);
    }

    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target) {
        return getLayoutSize(target, false);
    }

    public void layoutContainer(Container target) {
        Insets insets = target.getInsets();
        int count = target.getComponentCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Component component = target.getComponent(i);
            if (component.isVisible()) {
                Rectangle r = getComponentBounds(component, true);
                component.setBounds(insets.left + r.x, insets.top + r.y, r.width, r.height);
            }
        }

    }

    public void addLayoutComponent(Component component, Object constraints) {
        if (constraints instanceof XYConstraints)
            info.put(component, constraints);
    }

    public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target) {
        return new Dimension(0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff);
    }

    public float getLayoutAlignmentX(Container target) {
        return 0.5F;
    }

    public float getLayoutAlignmentY(Container target) {
        return 0.5F;
    }

    public void invalidateLayout(Container container) {
    }

    public Rectangle getComponentBounds(Component component, boolean doPreferred) {
        XYConstraints constraints = (XYConstraints) info.get(component);
        if (constraints == null)
            constraints = defaultConstraints;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(constraints.getX(), constraints.getY(), constraints.getW(), constraints.getH());
        if (r.width <= 0 || r.height <= 0) {
            Dimension d = doPreferred ? component.getPreferredSize() : component.getMinimumSize();
            if (r.width <= 0)
                r.width = d.width;
            if (r.height <= 0)
                r.height = d.height;
        }
        return r;
    }

    public Dimension getLayoutSize(Container target, boolean doPreferred) {
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
        if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
            int count = target.getComponentCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Component component = target.getComponent(i);
                if (component.isVisible()) {
                    Rectangle r = getComponentBounds(component, doPreferred);
                    dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, r.x + r.width);
                    dim.height = Math.max(dim.height, r.y + r.height);
                }
            }

        }
        if (width > 0)
            dim.width = width;
        if (height > 0)
            dim.height = height;
        Insets insets = target.getInsets();
        dim.width += insets.left + insets.right;
        dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom;
        return dim;
    }

}

class XYConstraints implements Cloneable, Serializable {

    private int x;

    private int y;

    private int w;

    private int h;

    public XYConstraints() {
        this(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public XYConstraints(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getW() {
        return w;
    }

    public void setW(int w) {
        this.w = w;
    }

    public int getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(int h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + h;
        result = prime * result + w;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
        // return x ^ y * 37 ^ w * 43 ^ h * 47;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (that instanceof XYConstraints) {
            XYConstraints other = (XYConstraints) that;
            return other.x == x && other.y == y && other.w == w && other.h == h;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Object clone() {
        return new XYConstraints(x, y, w, h);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("XYConstraints [x=").append(x).append(", y=").append(y).append(", w=").append(w).append(", h=").append(h).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

**My first attempt was:**

```
     for (y = 375; y > 0; y = y - 50)
     children[1].add(new JButton("1"), new XYConstraints(x, y, w, h));

     for (y = 325, x = 0; y > 0 && x < 280; y = y - 50, x = x + 40)
     children[2].add(new JButton("2"), new XYConstraints(x, y, w, 2 * h));

     for (y = 275, x = 0; y > 0 && x < 240; y = y - 50, x = x + 40)
     children[3].add(new JButton("3"), new XYConstraints(x, y, w, 3 * h));
```

but something's missing like a loop for "children[i]".I'm sure there is a better solution to improve the loop Any idea of improvement or suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: Does your first attempt work, and you just want to eliminate further duplication?  Or did your first attempt not work and you want help with that?

Comment: In fact, I'm looking something to deal with children[i]. if I have 10 children, I have to write 10 for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
for( int i=1; i<=3; i++ ) {
    x = 0;
    for( y=375-((i-1)*50; y>0; y-=50, x+=40 ) {
        children[i].add(new JButton((String)i), new XYConstraints(x, y, w, i*h));
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3748551 - I know it may answer your question, but it is not a good solution. Now you are writing layout management code outside the layout manager. Take the time to learn how to write a layout manager properly.

Comment: camickr is right that the cleanest separation of concerns here would be to write a self-contained layout manager that lays out each button 50 pixels above and 40 pixels right of the previous one, so that each time you call add() the layout manager can automatically figure out where to place the element.  Is it worth the trouble?  I say no in this limited case, even though that's the cleanest separation of concerns.  But I'd break the inner for loop into a helper method (to which you'd pass children[i]), to make that part of it more modular.

Comment: `Is it worth the trouble? I say no in this limited case,` - I would disagree :) If you go to the trouble to attempt to make a layout manager then do it properly. Learn how to write a layout manager in a simple case and it will make the harder cases easier when you need it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

> I write my own layout because existing layout manager don't meet my requirements

Right idea, but your implementation is incorrect. The fact that you need to provide the x/y values means you are not using a layout manager but just hardcoding some values.

Instead you need to provide information to the layout manager to define the parameters of the layout, maybe something like:

```
MyLayout layout = new MyLayout(xSize, ySize, xOffset, yOffset);
```

So for the first panel you would use:

```
MyLayout layout = new MyLayout(50, 50, 0, 50);
```

This code would say that each component is (50, 50). As you add components to the panel you change the x offset by 0 and the y offset = -50.

You know you have 8 buttons so you can use math to figure out the width/height of the panel. You can then use a loop inside the layout manager to position each component.

So now you add components to the panel like:

```
panel.add( new JButton("1") );
panel.add( new JButton("2") );
panel.add( new JButton("3") );
```

For the second panel you might use:

```
MyLayout layout = new MyLayout(50, 100, 50, 50);
```

So this time it means each button know has a size of (50, 100) and each button is placed (50, -50) to the previous button.

This is how layout managers should be created. You should not need complex loops to build the constraints of each component that you add to the panel. That is the job of the layout manager.